# Manipulating an array in memory via the arm c inline assembler

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

```
int smplSize = 48;
int Smpl[48];

for(int i = 0; i < smplSize; i++) Smpl[i] = 0x0;
Smpl[smplSize-1] = 0x1;

int *ptrToSmpl = &Smpl[0];

printf("Sample @%p of Size %i :\n",(void*)ptrToSmpl,smplSize);

asm volatile(

             "@ ------------------------------------------------- \n"
             "@ Invert the sample \n"
             "@ ------------------------------------------------- \n"

            //"0:                \n"
            "ldr r2,[r3] \n"
            //"cmp r2,#0x1          \n"
            //"bne 1f             \n"
            "add r2,#0x1       \n"

            //"add r2,#0x1          \n"
            "str r2,[r3]        \n"

            //"ldr r1, .0             \n"
            //"bx  r1             \n"
            //"1:                \n"


            :
            : "r"   (ptrToSmpl)
            : "r3", "memory"

             );

printf("Sample[0] = %i" , Smpl[0]);
```

Edit:

As you can see I want to manipulate a variable of an array via the inline assembler on arm, but I always get a segfault. How can I access the memory without segfault?

```
printf("Hello inline asmTest start!\n\n");

int smplSize = 48;
int Smpl[48];

for(int i = 0; i < smplSize; i++) Smpl[i] = 0x0;
Smpl[smplSize-1] = 0x1;

int *ptrToSmpl = &Smpl[0];

printf("Sample @%p of Size %i :\n",(void*)ptrToSmpl,smplSize);

asm volatile(

             "@ ------------------------------------------------- \n"
             "@ Invert the sample \n"
             "@ ------------------------------------------------- \n"

            //"0:                \n"

            "ldr r2,%[ptrToSmpl] \n"
            //"cmp r2,#0x1          \n"
            //"bne 1f             \n"
            "add r2,#0x1       \n"

            //"add r2,#0x1          \n"
            "str r2,%[ptrToSmpl]        \n"

            //"ldr r1, .0             \n"
            //"bx  r1             \n"
            //"1:                \n"


            :
            : [ptrToSmpl]"r"   (ptrToSmpl)
            :

             );

printf("Sample[0] = %i" , Smpl[0]);
```

Ok, I did so, but now I get a "/tmp/cczQDyiw.s|72|Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up|" when compiling it.

BTW: Can I "org [Adress of the programm]" the inline asm code ?

```
printf("Hello inline asmTest start!\n\n");

int smplSize = 48;
int Smpl[48];

for(int i = 0; i < smplSize; i++) Smpl[i] = 0x0;
Smpl[smplSize-1] = 0x1;

int *ptrToSmpl = &Smpl[0];

printf("Sample @%p of Size %i :\n",(void*)ptrToSmpl,smplSize);

asm volatile(

             "@ ------------------------------------------------- \n"
             "@ Invert the sample \n"
             "@ ------------------------------------------------- \n"

            "init:                \n"
            "ldr   r0,%[ptrToSmpl] \n"

            "loop :                 \n"
            "ldr r4,[r0]        \n"
            "cmp r4,#0x0          \n"
            "bne  end             \n"

            "add r4,#0x1          \n"
            "str r4,[r0]        \n"

            "add r0,#0x1       \n"


            "b  loop             \n"
            "end:                \n"


            :
            : [ptrToSmpl]"r"   (ptrToSmpl)
            :  "r0" , "r4", "memory"

             );

printf("Sample[0] = %i" , Smpl[0]);
```

Edit 2:

As you can see above theres still a bug in the adressing I think.
The error message now is:
"/tmp/ccE69oZd.s|75|Error: undefined symbol r6 used as an immediate value|"
but there's no r6 anywhere.

Comment: How do you make sure ptrToSmpl ends in r3? http://goo.gl/1aJ5t8

Comment: Please start a new thread if you have another question - it's hard to follow your edits and it's hard to answer them properly, once an answer is already given and accepted. BTW - your idea to use `adr` is completely wrong and shows that you have no idea what this instruction does...

Comment: sry using adr was a mistake it should be ldr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `%[ptrToSmpl]` inside square brackets - you want to load/store from/to the address that is in the register.

This `ldr r2,%[ptrToSmpl]` gets translated into `ldr r2,rX` - nonsense

This `ldr r2,[%[ptrToSmpl]]`  `ldr r2,[rX]` - correct

Moreover - you should put r2 into the list of clobbered registers, as you overwrite what compiler puts there. Add "r2" (with quotes) after the last (third) colon.

Comment: how can i increment the ptr's value?

Comment: Just observe how your compiler does that (; Write a simple loop and see how it is transformed into assembly (you can generate assembly listing like this `arm-none-eabi-objdump --demangle -S file.elf > file.lss`). If you want to increment the address register _AFTER_ the load (or store), you do it like this `ldr r1, [r2], #4` (the 4 is obviously the number that is added to r2). I suggest you to write your code in C and inspect the assembly - you'll then either see how well compiler does it (and decide not to write that yourself), or you'll see how such constructs are translated into assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hard code the registers that the assembly is supposed to use. Use the `%0`, `%1` etc notation to name the registers that correspond to the parameters that you are passing.

If you do so correctly you shouldn't need to use constraints such as `"memory"` in your case.