# Storing values in a 2d array via inline assembly in C

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I'm having trouble storing values into a 2D array from inline c.

I can read values from the array by using the `ldrb` instruction:

```
uint8_t r[4][4];
uint8_t i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = (i+1); j < 4; j++) {
        __asm__ __volatile__(
            "mov r0, %[ii]\n\t"
            "mov r1, %[jj]\n\t"
            "mov r2, #4\n\t"
            "mul r2, r2, r0\n\t"              // row*size
            "add r2, r2, r1\n\t"              // row*size + column
            "ldrb r2, [%[rr], r2]\n\t"        // Load r[i][j] into r2
            : 
            : [ii]"h" (i),[jj]"h" (j),[rr]"l" (r)
            : "r0","r1","r2"
        );
    }
}
```

But am unable to get the follow using the `strb` instruction to work. I am able to compile it, but it doesn't seem to actually store the values in the array.

```
uint8_t r[4][4];
uint8_t i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = (i+1); j < 4; j++) {
        __asm__ __volatile__(
            "mov r0, %[ii]\n\t"
            "mov r1, %[jj]\n\t"
            "mov r2, #4\n\t"
            "mul r2, r2, r0\n\t"        // row*size
            "add r2, r2, r1\n\t"        // row*size + column
            "mov r0, #6\n\t"
            "strb r0, [%[rr], r2]\n\t"        // Store r0 in r[i][j]
            :[rr]"+l" (r)
            :[ii]"l" (i),[jj]"l" (j)
            :"r0","r1","r2","memory"
        );
    }
}
```

When I run as above I get the following error:

```
./src/main.c:52:17: warning: asm operand 3 probably doesn't match constraints
                 __asm__ __volatile__(
```

If I change the constraint to `=l`instead I get the following error instead:

```
error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
                 __asm__ __volatile__(
```

I've also tried adding `uint8_t *rr = &r[0][0];` and using `rr` instead as suggested in another StackOverflow post. This doesn't give me the above error but doesn't write to the expected memory locations.

Here i am unsure what to put for `[rr]"+l" (r)` to get it to work. I have tried the m constraint also. I have tried adding the "memory" to the clobber list as I read this is meant for modifying memory addresses that are not listed in the input/output.

I'm at a dead end at the moment, I can't find any example of people writing to arrays, i've tried to follow [Manipulating an array in memory via the arm c inline assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058767/manipulating-an-array-in-memory-via-the-arm-c-inline-assembler) but I can't get it to work with the strb instruction with an offset. I'm sure it's something small i'm busy, any suggestions would be great as i'm stuck.

Is the way I have passed in the array correct? Do I have the correct clobbers? Am I missing something else along those lines?

Thanks

Note: I'm limited to 16-bit thumb instructions.

Comment: _"unable to do the same"_ is not a good problem description. What happens? Does it compile? Does it fault? Does it produce wrong result? If so, what did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: I assumed it would be clear I was doing something wrong. But understand that may not have been clear at that point. I think the rest of the question though naturally raises these questions: Is the way I have passed in variables correct? Do I have the correct clobbers? Am I missing something else along those lines?

Comment: You calculate `r2` but then don't use it in the `strb`. Compare to your `ldrb`. It would be a lot easier for us if we didn't have to check for **ALL** possible errors, and could focus on the one that you have.

Comment: Yes I understand that. That was a typo. I have updated the post there. Thanks.

Comment: can you compile with gcc -S and show us the output ? perhaps the problem's more obvious then

Comment: Looks like it should work **you should really tell us the problem**.

Comment: "arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated."

Comment: @Jester I've added some more information on different things I have tried. I'm not sure how I can make the problem clearer. It's not running as expected. I want to write to a 2D array, the expected result would be to actually write to the array, which it isn't. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help :)

Comment: So that means it compiles and doesn't fault. I have asked you that, was it so hard to answer? Now what does it mean _"it doesn't actually write to the array"_? Have you dumped the array, checked whether it writes somewhere else maybe? Does it maybe write to the correct place, but wrong value? Come on! Also, use a debugger and check what the register values are when the `strb` executes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I originally got confused.
I have dumped out the array values from code and they are not updating as specified in the assembly. It doesn't write to the correct place, when i dumped them the values were unchanged. I am unable to use a debugger at the moment so can not verify that. 
So from what you can see here, is this code correct with regards to the correct constraints and variables used in the output area of the asm block. Along with the clobber list?

Comment: I think if we are running as above, the error "warning: asm operand 3 probably doesn't match constraints
                 __asm__ __volatile__(" is probably of significance.

Comment: Not sure where the value to write even comes from ... `mov r0, %6` ??? You don't have a `%6`. Constraints should be exactly the same as the read case, except of course you want an input operand for the value, and not an output (but you don't have an output in the first block...)

Comment: Yes this was a typo. It still gives the same error however. https://godbolt.org/g/VgFf04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134394/discussion-between-dave-peachy-and-jester).